# Rails wrong static location picking

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am new to rails and implementing a demo app. I have this code in my 'app/view/layout/applicatio.html.erb' file:

`<%= stylesheet_link_tag "scaffold" %>`

but when I run it and debug in my browser I see this path expands to:

`<link href="/assets/scaffold.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

I am not able to understand that from where this `assets` folder is coming into picture? this is also causing the problem in the loading of my stylesheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this stuff here.
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

In application.html.erb

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>
```

in the applications.css

```
 *= require_tree .
```

This row means all .css file in app/assets/stylesheets will be included.

Comment: But I don't have any 'assets' folder!

Comment: Got it working. Actually there is a assets folder in the 'app' and not in the public directory. Hmm, don't know why there are two places for the static content. I will read your link.